# Macvim: horizontal scroll bar

Tags: scroll, vim, macvim

Using macvim, which is awesome.  However I would love to have some kind of horizontal scroll bar.  Is this possible?

Answer (score 5):

You can get a horizontal scroll bar in GUI vims by doing `:set go+=b`. See `:h 'go'` for discussion. I've just tested this on my macvim, and it works fine (make sure you also `:set nowrap` of course...)

Comment: Huh, you are correct that does create a scroll bar, however it does not *really work*.  On my trackpad when I side scroll it does not scroll.  +1 for the answer but I am gong to leave the question open.

Comment: For reasons discussed here (http://tinyurl.com/kwp4rt) this can't be done right now, but it is a planned enhancement for MacVim. You should talk with the developers on vim_mac if you want to make this happen faster.

Comment: UPDATE: from the latest version (7.3 BETA at http://github.com/b4winckler/macvim/downloads) MacVim has got proper horizontal scroll wheel support/track pad scrolling. It was just announced on vim_mac.

Comment: Using the above suggestion creates a permanent horizontal scrollbar, even when one isn't needed. Is it possible to have vim only create the horizonal scrollbar when the length of the line/text requires it?